# How to put a human on Mars

Tags: discussion

Not sure if this should be a question here or not.  But BBC just published [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-23349496), which happens to be like two days after our public beta started.

Is there a relationship in the timing?

Comment: Nah. Probably not.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask about this, if you have a question about it, sure.

Please note, that the news published by the BCC is about 'just another' mission *concept* or *design*. There are plenty of them, maybe a few just for human missions to Mars alone each year. Have a look at whether this is backed up by agencies and politicians. *This would be great news then.* If not, assume that it wont fly sometimes 'soon'. I do not see a relationship with SE and this beta, but you can always mail the people behind the study ([Dr Tom Pike, team leader for this project](http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/people/w.t.pike)) or the BBC (the author of the story is [Neil Bowdler](https://twitter.com/Neil_Bowdler)) and ask :-)